# Where do I get Exp Share in Pokemon Emerald?

Tags: pokemon-ruby-sapphire-emerald

Where can I find the Exp.Share? And also how early in the game can I get it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get it from the Devon President in Rustboro City after having delivered his letter to Steven in Dewford Town.